# Container for sparse matrix

Tags: c++, matrix, containers, sparse-matrix

I need to implement in C++ a Container for a sparse Matrix. The Container has the functions to add and to modify a value of the matrix ( I am not allowed to use std:: vector or array or anything from the standard library) .And I need to use dynamic arrays.How could I do that,has anyone an idea?

Comment: `std::map<std:pair<int, int>, data_t>` can be used for a generic sparse matrix.  So start there with a non-templated implementation.  When you have some code post it here.  Please read [ask] with a [mcve]

Comment: if you cannot use standard containers then you should write your own. Don't expect it to be trivial, there are lots of opportunities to get it wrong. Did they not tell you what you should use instead when they told you not to use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0):

> How could I do that,has anyone an idea?

Do the simplest thing that could possibly work, and don’t be shy about changing gears as needed. Could a linked list work? Try that. If it turns out not to be fast enough, replace with something faster.

> And I need to use dinamic arrays.

So there’s your answer: if you need to use dynamic arrays, that’ll be your storage mechanism.

The thing about sparse matrices is that the majority of entries are 0, so even a linear search through the non-zero entries is quick because there aren’t that many. So what if you had a list of entries where each entry included its position in the matrix and a value? That seems like all you need to meet your requirements.